# how to use the submitted value in a function to another function and then use the value using shortcode in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to concatenate "**Hi**" with the submitted value[**$x**] and show it in a page or post by using *shortcode*. I am trying to send the value[**$x**] to another function[**display_output($x)**] and then using that function[**display_output**] name in **add_shortcode()**, but it only showing "**Hi**" and not the submitted value[**$x**].If my approach is wrong then is there any other way to use the submitted value in a page or post by using shortcode. I am new in wordpress plugin development. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  Iron Man
Plugin URI:   https://rajbiswas.com
Description:  My Plugin Dev.
Version:      0.1
Author:       RB

*/

/*Adding option page in dashboard*/
function my_plugin_settings()
{
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin',
                    'myCust Form',
                    'administrator',
                    'insert-my-plugin_bro',
                    'my_plugin_settings_page',
                    'dashicons-translation',
                    '60'
                );  
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_settings');

/*registering input group and field*/
function my_plugin_options()
{
    register_setting('my-form-group','user_input_name');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_options');



function my_plugin_settings_page()
{
    ?>
    <h1>hello fellas</h1>

    <form  action="options.php" method="post">
        <?php settings_fields('my-form-group'); ?>

        <input type="text" name="user_input_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('user_input_name')) ?>" >
        <?php //submit_button(); ?>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" >
    <form>  

    <?php
    $x = get_option('user_input_name');
    display_output($x);     //Sending $x to another function and trying to use it using shortcode. 
}

function display_output($x)
{   
    echo "HI"." ".$x;   //I want to concatenate "Hi" with $x and print it in page/post wherever I use shortcode([test-shortcode]). But it is not working.
}
add_shortcode('test-shortcode', 'display_output');
?>
```

Comment: So, it works when you call display_output($x) in my_plugin_settings_page(), but not when you're using the short code directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are save input to options try retrieve this option in your shortcode function. You can use `get_option` globally.

```
function display_output($x)
{   
    $x = get_option('user_input_name');
    echo "HI"." ".$x;   //I want to concatenate "Hi" with $x and print it in page/post wherever I use shortcode([test-shortcode]). But it is not working.
}
add_shortcode('test-shortcode', 'display_output');
```

Comment: Done. Thanks Maxim.